# Execute command using Win32

Tags: c++, winapi, cmd, createprocess

I would like to execute shell command to update firmware to my procesor ATMega 2560 like this:

```
avrdude.exe -c breakout -P ft0 -p m2560 -U flash:w:\"file.cpp.hex\":a
```

I can do it by ShellExecute() function:

```
ShellExecute(0, L"open", L"cmd.exe", L"/C avrdude.exe -c breakout -P ft0 -p     m2560 -U flash:w:\"file.cpp.hex\":a > log.txt", 0, SW_HIDE);
```

But I want to redirect output buffer, so I think I should use CreateProcess() function. I tried this but it hasn't worked.

```
CreateProcess(NULL, L"cmd /C avrdude.exe -c breakout -P ft0 -p m2560 -U flash:w:\"file.cpp.hex\":a", NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Well, what does your `CreateProcess()` return? Assuming it's an error, what does `GetLastError()` say?

Answer (score 6):

Use `CreateProcess()` instead of `ShellExecute()`, and provide your own pipes so you can read the process's output.  MSDN has an article on that topic:

[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx)

For example:

```
LPWSTR cmdLine[] = L"avrdude.exe -c breakout -P ft0 -p m2560 -U flash:w:\"file.cpp.hex\":a";

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = {0};
sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

HANDLE hStdOutRd, hStdOutWr;
HANDLE hStdErrRd, hStdErrWr;

if (!CreatePipe(&hStdOutRd, &hStdOutWr, &sa, 0))
{
    // error handling...
}

if (!CreatePipe(&hStdErrRd, &hStdErrWr, &sa, 0))
{
    // error handling...
}

SetHandleInformation(hStdOutRd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
SetHandleInformation(hStdErrRd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);

STARTUPINFO si = {0};
si.cbSize = sizeof(si);
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
si.hStdInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
si.hStdOutput = hStdOutWr;
si.hStdError = hStdErrWr;

PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};

if (!CreateProcessW(NULL, cmdLine, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    // error handling...
}
else
{
    // read from hStdOutRd and hStdErrRd as needed until the process is terminated...

    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}

CloseHandle(hStdOutRd);
CloseHandle(hStdOutWr);
CloseHandle(hStdErrRd);
CloseHandle(hStdErrWr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem was resolved! 
Full code:

```
STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(STARTUPINFO) };
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

if (!CreateProcess(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    L" /C avrdude.exe -c breakout -P ft0 -p m2560 -U flash:w:\"file.cpp.hex\":a",
    NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))    
{
    printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: That's no good. The second parameter must be writeable. And you also leak handles.

Comment: Also, why invoke `cmd.exe` at all, when you can invoke `avrdude.exe` directly instead?

Comment: @DavidHeffernanL you don't know whether he is leaking handles or not, as he did not show the code that is run when `CreateProcess()` succeeds.

Comment: [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx): *"lpCommandLine: If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation."*